# Is it possible to use openvpn and apache together?

Tags: centos, openvpn

I have a production server that serves my site. I am using apache, mysql and nodejs for my site.

If i install the openvpn for using my personal purposes, not reverse proxy or something what happens? I am afraid about to broke the apache or nodejs

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN by default runs on port 1194 UDP, which is not at all conflicting with the all-TCP services you have running.  These are the default ports of those services:

- Apache – Port 80 TCP (HTTP) and port 443 TCP (HTTPS)
- MySQL – Port 3306 TCP
- Node.js – Depends, but TCP

You can run any of these services on a different port, if you'd like, and [OpenVPN can also run over TCP](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/500854c3fc956b274790991e4d6771ad9bf6f641/sample/sample-config-files/server.conf#L34).

---

If you're concerned about breaking other services on the same machine, consider running OpenVPN in a [virtual machine](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-kvm-on-centos-7-rhel-7-headless-server/) or [container](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-and-use-lxd-on-centos-linux-7-x-server/).  That way, if you mess up some configuration inside the container, your other services probably won't be affected.

You may need to [port forward](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912041836/https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/19/html/Security_Guide/sec-Configure_Port_Forwarding-CLI.html) OpenVPN if you're sharing one public IPv4 address.